# How can I integrate some code that is being rendered on html tag within my custom module in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a CJ affiliate module that its already working perfectly fine:

Please see structure here:
http://screencast.com/t/21tsCh9loPSc

The module has an admin section where some settings are filled in:
cookie lifetime, affiliate id, etc.

Then I have to generate a JSON object on the HTML tag only on the success page.
This file is called udo.phtml, but its outside the module structure.

Is there anyway I can integrate that into the module itself?
http://screencast.com/t/jkJhKbHvk2

udo.phtml file code

```
<?php

class xxx_Commissionjunction_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Get SKU, quantity, price and discount amount for each product in a given order
     * @param object $order
     * @return array
     */
    private function _getOrderProductsList($order)
    {
        $orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
        $purchasedSkus = array();
        $count_orderItems = count($orderItems);
        for($i = 0; $i < $count_orderItems; $i++) {
            $purchasedSkus[$i] = array(
                'ITEM' => $orderItems[$i]['sku'],
                'QTY' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['qty_ordered'],0), // no decimals
                'AMT' => number_format($orderItems[$i]['price'],2), // 2 decimal places
                'DCNT' => number_format(abs($orderItems[$i]['discount_amount']),2)
            );
        }

        return $purchasedSkus;
    }

     /**
     * Get the Universal Data (JSON) Object for Commission Junction.
     * This object contains the order details passed on to Commission Junction for reporting purposes
     * on the Checkout Success / Order Confirmation page.
     * Notes:
     *  - CID, TYPE AND CURRENCY are hard coded
     * @param string $orderId
     * @return JSON object Universal Data Object for Commission Junction $json_masterTmsUdp
     */
    public function getCommissionJunctionUdo()
    {
        $lastOrderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
            ->getLastRealOrderId();

        $orderId = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
            ->loadByIncrementId($lastOrderId)
            ->getEntityId();

        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $udo = array();
        //$udo['CID'] = '1531288';
        $udo['CID'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('luisvalenciasection/luisvalenciagroup/cid');


        $LastOrdertime= $order->getCreatedAt();
        $OrderCollection=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('customer_email',$order->getData('customer_email'))
            ->setOrder('created_at','asc');
        $fstoredetime= $OrderCollection->getFirstItem()->getCreatedAt();

        if($fstoredetime==$LastOrdertime)
        {
            // new customer
            //$udo['TYPE'] = '373626';
            $udo['TYPE'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('luisvalenciasection/luisvalenciagroup/type_new_customer');
        }
        else
        {
            //old customer
            //$udo['TYPE'] = '373627';
            $udo['TYPE'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('luisvalenciasection/luisvalenciagroup/type_old_customer');
        }

        $udo['CURRENCY'] = 'USD';
        $udo['OID'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        $udo['DISCOUNT'] = number_format(abs($order->discount_amount),2);

        $order_coupon_code = $order->coupon_code;
        if(!is_null($order_coupon_code) && !empty($order_coupon_code))
        {
            $udo['COUPON'] = $order_coupon_code;
        }

        $udo['PRODUCTLIST'] = self::_getOrderProductsList($order);

        if(Mage::getModel('core/cookie')->get('ref') == 'cj') {
            $udo['FIRECJ'] = "TRUE";
        }
        else {
            $udo['FIRECJ'] = "FALSE";
        }

        $masterTmsUdo['CJ'] = $udo;
        $json_masterTmsUdo = json_encode($masterTmsUdo);

        Mage::log('Udo: '.$json_masterTmsUdo, null, 'cj.log');

        return $json_masterTmsUdo;

    }
}
?>
<script>var MasterTmsUdo = <?php $myObject = new xxx_Commissionjunction_Helper_Data(); echo $myObject->getCommissionJunctionUdo(); ?></script>
<script>/*DO NOT ALTER *** The Printer Depo*/(function(e){var t="1340",n=document,r,i,s={http:"http://cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js",https:"https://secure-cdn.mplxtms.com/s/MasterTMS.min.js"},o=s[/\w+/.exec(window.location.protocol)[0]];i=n.createElement("script"),i.type="text/javascript",i.async=!0,i.src=o+"#"+t,r=n.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],r.parentNode.insertBefore(i,r),i.readyState?i.onreadystatechange=function(){if(i.readyState==="loaded"||i.readyState==="complete")i.onreadystatechange=null}:i.onload=function(){try{e()}catch(t){}}})(function(){});</script>
```

Comment: code that you attached here is not udo.phtml. Its your helper file

Comment: no, its udo.phtml http://screencast.com/t/8a2AQv5U

Comment: oops !!! this  cant be.. why do u define a class inside phtml file. You are trying to extend it from core helper class also... This is completely wrong. Templates are place that are used to store view logic..

Comment: can you please help me? how should I do this then? teamviewer?

Comment: I am beginning with magento devlopment

Comment: Before starting coding, you just want to make a structure understading. This is required for every frameworks'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59405/discussion-between-l-v-and-programmer-rkt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know what you are intending to tell us by specifying, you need to integrate a p)html file with your custom module, by showing your file structure. Yes of course, that template file is outside your module structure. But you cannot attach that template file to your module (structure wise). This is simple and logical once you think about it. Just think, how Magento integrate template files with to its core modules, even though templates(phtml files), js and css files reside outside of its module scope(structure wise).

So we have a backend logic and view logic seperated in two section in magento. Magento now uses a layer called layout XML, which is used to connect these two sections.

```
Magento Modules   <------->   Layout        <-----------> view files
(lives in app/code)   (app/design/.../layout)   (templates :- app/design/.../templates
                                                       css,js,images :- skin)
```

So layouts stands in between modules and view and connect them. The advantage for this approach is two

1. This makes Magento highly extendable
2. This makes different logics seperated in structure wise. The importance is, we can now know where is a view logic resides, where controllers resides, where model resides. This logics seperated and most importantly indeperndent to each other.

Here is an another approach. Magento use module approach in it. Mean each module do different purposes and are independent each other. That means, if we made any changes in one module, it would not alter any logics of any other module. Each module has its own Model and its own controllers. That means Modules can individually talk to database and can connect its own module to View. Since Each modules create their own world in this way, modules are purely independent each other.

Now in order to communicate with view section, Magento uses layout layer. This is where everything get connecteD. Layouts used to set templates, js and css to each module in Magento. Thus they can access properties of that module in it and do Magics !!!. Layout is the place where each individual module get in touch. Hence it is very very important to study layout layer that using by Magento.

```
overview

Module1                                                      TEMPLATES(hold design)
|
------ controllers(private)                                      
|                                                             JS
------ Models(private)          LAYOUTS                       Css
                          (Here every logics unites)         Images
Module2

Module3

so on
(resides app/code)        (resides app/design../layout)      (reside app/design/..template and in skin)
```

so on
Once you mastered it, Magento will starts to obey you... Otherwise she will show hesitation. She is such a noty girl. Thats why I love her :)